# How to shuffle a substring

Tags: c#, string, substring, shuffle

I have a string **s** of size **kn**.

I want to shuffle each of the **k** **n**-sized blocks of **s** (given **k** and **n**).

Example: **s** = *abcdabcdabcd*, **n** = 4, **k** = 3.

```
BEGIN: abcdabcdabcd

 abcd       abcd       abcd
 └─┬─┘      └─┬─┘      └─┬─┘      
shuffle    shuffle    shuffle
   ↓          ↓          ↓
 bdac       adbc       cdba

RESULT: bdacadbccdba
```

Comment: It is guaranteed that the size of **s** is **kn**. To simplify, both **k** and **n** are at least 2.

Comment: What do you want to happen if, e.g. your string contains a surrogate pair or combining diacritics? When you say the size of the string, do you mean UTF-16 code units (in which case a surrogate pair counts as 2), the length in code points, or the length in text elements (so that, e.g. an e followed by a combining acute accent counts as 1)?

Comment: When I say "size of string", I mean the number of characters it contains. You can consider the string contains only chars from *a* to *z* (97, ...,122 ASCII)

Comment: This should definitely be on **[codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)** and not here. And as far as I think, usually we do not act like a writing service?

Comment: @Daniel - ok under that restriction things become simpler. You need to be careful with terms like "character" because in Unicode this is not a well-defined concept (and the CLR is somewhat unhelpful here by exposing the gory details of the UTF-16 encoding to the programmer via `System.Char`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var s = "abcdabcdabcd";
var k = 3;
var n = 4;
var result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    var current = s.Substring((i * n), n);
    var shuffled = string.Join("",current.OrderBy(x=>rnd.Next()));
    result += shuffled;
}
```

One Result :

```
"bcadabcdbcda"
```

Answer (score 3):

One nasty Linq statement

**Given**

```
public static Random _rnd=new Random();

public static string WeirdShuffle(string input, int n) 
   => string.Concat(input.ToCharArray()
                         .Select((s, i) => (s, i))
                         .GroupBy(x => x.i / n)
                         .Select(g => string.Concat(g.Select(x => x.s)
                                                     .OrderBy(x => _rnd.Next()))));
```

**Usage**

```
Console.WriteLine(WeirdShuffle("abcdabcdabcd",4));
```

---

**Additional Resources**

- [String.ToCharArray Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tochararray?view=netframework-4.7.2)

  - > Copies the characters in this instance to a Unicode character array.
- [Enumerable.Select Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2)

  - > Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.
- [Enumerable.GroupBy Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.7.2)

  - > Groups the elements of a sequence.
- [Enumerable.OrderBy Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.7.2)

  - > Sorts the elements of a sequence in ascending order.
- [String.Concat Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.concat?view=netframework-4.7.2)

  - > Concatenates one or more instances of String

Comment: I chose another answer just for readability, your answer uses a lot of concepts and its time complexity seems to be the same than Mehrdad's answer, which is easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work. It's essentially a modified Fisher-Yates shuffle:

```
private static Random _random = new Random(); 

public static string ShuffleSubstrings(string input, int n, int k)
{
    if (input.Length != (n * k))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Length of input is not equal to kn");
    }

    var characters = input.ToCharArray();
    for (int g = 0; g < input.Length; g += n)
    {
        ShuffleSubarray(characters, g, n);
    }
    return new string(characters);
}

private static void ShuffleSubarray<T>(T[] array, int startPosition, int length)
{
    // For loop to handle individual group
    for (int i = startPosition; i < startPosition + length; ++i)
    {
        // shuffle taken from taken from https://www.dotnetperls.com/fisher-yates-shuffle, modified to work with groups)
        int r = i + _random.Next(length - (i % length));
        T tmp = array[r];
        array[r] = array[i];
        array[i] = tmp;
    }
}
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/XTU58754)

Answer (score 1):

I like this one:

```
private static Random _rnd = new Random();

public static string ShuffleSubstrings(string input, int n, int k)
{
    if (input.Length != (n * k))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Length of input is not equal to kn");
    }

    return String.Join("",
        from i in Enumerable.Range(0, k)
        from x in
            from y in input.Substring(i * n, n)
            orderby _rnd.Next()
            select y
        select x);
}
```

Comment: You answer fits in well with your name hehe, couldn't understand these SQL logics.

Comment: @Daniel - The logic is no different from the answer that you selected. It should be a little easier I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string Shuffle(string str, int shuffleSize)
{
    if (str.Length % shuffleSize != 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
    var result = Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length / shuffleSize)
        .Select(i =>
            SmallShuffle(str.Substring(i * shuffleSize, shuffleSize))
        );

    return string.Join("", result);
}

public string SmallShuffle(string str)
{
    char[] array = str.ToCharArray();
    Random rng = new Random();
    int n = array.Length;
    while (n > 1)
    {
        n--;
        int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
        var value = array[k];
        array[k] = array[n];
        array[n] = value;
    }
    return new string(array);
}
```

Usage:

```
var s = "123456789123";
int k = 4;
var shuffled = Shuffle(s, k);
```

Heavily influenced by these two answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1450797/4949005

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4740014/4949005

Answer (score 0):

```
 static string Shffule(string str,int blockSize)
        {
            Random randomIndex= new Random();
            for (int indexInString = 0; indexInString < str.Length; indexInString+= blockSize)
            {
                for (int shufflesInBlock = 0; shufflesInBlock < blockSize; shufflesInBlock++)
                {
                    var firstRandomIndex = randomIndex.Next(indexInString, indexInString + blockSize);
                    var secondRandomIndex = randomIndex.Next(indexInString, indexInString + blockSize);
                    //str.Swap(firstRandomIndex, secondRandomIndex);
                }
            }
            return swapedString;
        }
```

there is a lot of ways to swap 2 chars string here so i will leave the string.Swap extension method to u

you can control how many shuffles per block from the nested loop by changing the shufflesInBlock < blockSize condition