# How to generate random alphanumeric string from a given string in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a string. I want to generate a random string from this string, by replacing a number by a random number. lower character by lower character and upper character by upper character. And remaining characters as it is.

I have written the below code. I need to call this method millions of time on different strings (string length is not more than 100 characters), It's taking too much time.

```
private static string GenerateRandomAlphanumericValue(string input) {
    char[] newStr = new char[input.Length];
    char[] alphaU = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();
    char[] alphaL = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray();
    char[] number = "0123456789".ToCharArray();
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) {
        if (char.IsNumber(input[i])) {

            int index = random.Next(0, number.Length);
            newStr[i] = number[index];
        }
        else if (char.IsUpper(input[i])) {
            int index = random.Next(0, alphaU.Length);
            newStr[i] = alphaU[index];
        }
        else if (char.IsLower(input[i])) {
            int index = random.Next(0, alphaL.Length);
            newStr[i] = alphaL[index];
        }
        else {
            newStr[i] = input[i];
        }
    }

    return string.Join("", newStr);
}
```

I need help in optimizing the code or there any be a different approach to solve the problem.

**Input:** vivEK123$% ~a

**Output:** ajrLW854$% ~w

Comment: Didn't this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739903/shuffle-string-c-sharp

Comment: Shuffling is different, read the question again.

Comment: You can eliminate the Join by just appending characters to end of of string newStr (change from char[]).  You can also eliminate ToCharArray() by use string SubString method.

Comment: @jdweng ToCharArray() to SubString? I didn't get you. how?

Comment: The scope of `IsUpper` might have a big impact on its performance. It has to account for culture and all Unicode codepoints in the general category Lu. You, apprently, are only interested in the letters and digits in the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block- a much simpler problem space.

Comment: @TomBlodget I didn't get your point? So how to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
static char[] alphaU = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();
static char[] alphaL = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray();
static char[] number = "0123456789".ToCharArray();
static Random random = new Random();
static StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);

private static string GenerateRandomAlphanumericValue(string input)
{
    sb.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (char.IsNumber(input[i]))
        {
            int index = random.Next(0, number.Length);
            sb.Append(number[index]);
        }
        else if (char.IsUpper(input[i]))
        {
            int index = random.Next(0, alphaU.Length);
            sb.Append(alphaU[index]);
        }
        else if (char.IsLower(input[i]))
        {
            int index = random.Next(0, alphaL.Length);
            sb.Append(alphaL[index]);
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(input[i]);
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using arrays, you could just randomize based on the ASCII-value range of characters. I'd also suggest using `StringBuilder` to build the result string.

```
public class Randomizer{
    private static Random rng = new Random();
    public static string RandomizeString(string input){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(char c in input){
            if(Char.IsNumber(c)){
                sb.Append(rng.Next(0,10));
            }
            else if(Char.IsLower(c)){
                sb.Append((char)rng.Next(97,123));
            }
            else if(Char.IsUpper(c)){
                sb.Append((char)rng.Next(65,91));
            }
            else{
                sb.Append(c);
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Note: `a-z` is ASCII `97-122`, `A-Z` is ASCII `65-90`, and `0-9` is just an integer cast to a string.

Comment: Benchmarking your solution against OP's original and @Bahrom's, while moving the Random generation alone cut down the execution by half, casting (either implicit in appending int for number part, and explicit in appending the lower and upper) increase your solution execution time about 50% against Bahrom's who avoided casting

Comment: `'A', 'Z' - 'A' + 1` would be easier to read (and calculated by the compiler).

Comment: BTW-`char` is a UTF-16 code unit; Nothing to do with ASCII.

Comment: @martheen didn't get you. Can you explain by example

Comment: @viveknuna The most expensive part of your original code is generating Random for each call. Which also would make the result for repeated calls with the same input to result with the same output (since the seed rely on time, they will be the same). Use a single Random, you halved the execution time. Put out the initialization for AlphaU, AlphaL and number, plus use StringBuilder which is optimized for this case, you got Bahrom's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little more efficient. I'm not sure about execution time :

```
       private static string GenerateRandomAlphanumericValue(string input)
        {
            string newStr = "";
            string alphaU = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            string alphaL = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            string number = "0123456789";
            Random random = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
                if (char.IsNumber(input[i]))
                {

                    int index = random.Next(0, number.Length);
                    newStr  += number[index];
                }
                else if (char.IsUpper(input[i]))
                {
                    int index = random.Next(0, alphaU.Length);
                    newStr += alphaU[index];
                }
                else if (char.IsLower(input[i]))
                {
                    int index = random.Next(0, alphaL.Length);
                    newStr += alphaL[index];
                }
                else
                {
                    newStr += input[i];
                }
            }

            return newStr;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The general principle is to move as much as possible out of loops and to use the least expensive techniques inside loops.

Random only needs to be constructed once.

StringBuilder is one of the more efficient ways of moving individually acquire Chars into a String. And, it needs to be constructed only once (but introduces thread safety issues).

Array indexing is one fast way to replace chain logic but might not be the fastest since there are only three ranges. (`if >= && <=` times three could be faster.)

`IsUpper` et al might have a big impact on its performance. They have to account for all Unicode codepoints in the general category Lu, Ll or Nd.

```
private static readonly Random random = new Random();
private static readonly StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);

// min and max are the replacement range for indexing Char.
private static readonly Char[] min = new Char[Char.MaxValue + 1];
private static readonly Char[] max = new Char[Char.MaxValue + 1];

static UserQuery()
{
    foreach (var range in new[] { 
        (min: 'A', max: 'Z'), 
        (min: 'a', max: 'z'), 
        (min: '0', max: '9') })
    {
        for (var c = range.min; c <= range.max; c++)
        {
            min[c] = range.min;
            max[c] = range.max;
        }
    }
}

private static String GenerateRandomAlphanumericValue(String input)
{
    sb.Clear();
    foreach (var c in input)
    {
        sb.Append((Char)random.Next(min[c], max[c]));
    }
    return sb.ToString();  
}
```

Comment: How to use UserQuery method?

Comment: It's the identifier for the class; Change I it to the name of your class. I made it a static initialization block because all the other state is static. You could make it all instance methods. One advantage of that could be to construct a few and run them in parallel if you can partition your millions of strings.

Comment: Yep, two million strings of 100 characters takes about 3 seconds when run on 3 or more threads vs 6 seconds on one thread (YMMV).